# How do I get sound back after connecting with x2go without rebooting?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop, nx

When I connect remotely over NX using x2go, for some reason, I get a pop-up on the server asking if I want to permanently forget the sound devices that have just been removed:

[image: screenshot 2]

The devices are not being removed, but somehow the connection to the server makes it *think* that they have been removed. In Phonon, these devices are then greyed out [image: screenshot]

I can't figure out how to get the sound working again on the server after the client disconnects without rebooting the server. Is there any way to restart the sound without rebooting the whole computer? Or refresh the list of hardware devices? I tried `sudo /etc/init.d/pulseaudio restart` with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a re-start,  shut down the system completely, doing a restart will hang up the sound card, and what you are currently using will not release control of it.

Comment: Hi Warren. Thanks for your answer, however, I don't think there is any difference in restarting or shutting down and turning the computer back on. And second, it really doesn't answer my question. I want the sound to work *without* shutting down or restarting, which is right in the title.